# Create Lambda function using Python API (Boto3) by using zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a zip file ready for the lambda function, but in the doc, the zip file is required to be read as binary (so it seems). I can open the zip file and read the files inside as binary, but how do I read the zip file as a binary?

The doc: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nevermind, a simple `open(file_name, 'rb').read()` does it for me. Forgot the 'b'.....